# Why am I getting an empty alert box?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have js function onsubmit forms

```
var bCancel = false;
var errors = new Array();
function validateNewsForm(form) {
    if (bCancel) {
        return true;
    } else {        
        errors = [];        
        var statusArray = new Array();
        statusArray.push(validateRequired(form));
        statusArray.push(validateMaxLength(form));
        statusArray.push(validateDate(form));

        for (status in statusArray) {
            if (!status) {              
                alert(errors.join('\n'));               
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

validateSmth() functions work fine. But when I input correct data I can't save because get empty alert. I have just one alert message and now that all validate functions gives true( in case correct data)

Why can I get empty alert?

Comment: Please show validateRequired/MaxLength/Date functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (status in statusArray) {
    if (!status) {
```

A `for in` loop gives you keys. For an array these are indices. So you're effectively doing `!0`, `!1`, etc, and `!0` evaluates to `true`.

You want a normal `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < statusArray.length; i++) {
    if (!statusArray[i]) {
```

Also, you're using `[]` and `new Array()` together. It's best to just use `[]` everywhere.

Comment: and whats to note is that processing an array with a for in loop is many times slower than with a for loop.

looking at jsperf too: http://jsperf.com/testarrloop

Answer (score 1):

because  for `status = 0` !status will be `true`.
Modified code:

```
for (var status  = 0; status < statusArray.length; status ++) {
            if (!statusArray[status] ) {              
                alert(errors.join('\n'));               
                return false;
            }
        }
```